# Custom Fields on Accounts layout page

Tags: salesforce

I have added few custom fields on Accounts and Contacts in Salesforce. When I view individual Account/Contact I can see those fields but when installed in other account. Those fields don't appear on Account/Contact page (though they are created). How to make them viewable on other salesforce account?

Comment: Have you checked the record types of the records that do not show these new fields? If they differ from the records that DO show the fields, then it's likely that you need to add the fields to the page layouts associated with this second record type.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have more than one Page Layout associated with different Accounts/Contacts record types.

When the fields were added, they were only added to some of the Account/Contact Page Layouts.

Those Accounts/Contacts that aren't showing the fields will have different record types to those that do.

When you deploy your custom fields to another Salesforce Org using a managed package they won't be automatically added to any existing page layouts they have.

They can be manually add after installing the package by either:

- Viewing an Account/Contact record that has the required Record Type and Page Layout. Then use the Edit Layout link.

[image: Salesforce Edit Layout Link]

- or Setup > App Setup > Customize > Accounts > Page Layouts > Action: Edit

Comment: actually I installed package on other account. One question I have is, when package is installed are all custom fields viewed on page layouts or you have to aks for permission for them?

Comment: Do you mean that you installed your custom fields into another Organization via a managed package? In that case you (or the customer) will need to add the custom fields to any existing page layouts they have.

Comment: yes I mean that, so how does this customer adds existing custom fields to his page layouts?